# Angular cant read object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have an array with two objects in it, assigned to $scope.items;

when i do

```
console.log($scope.items)
```

the output is:

```
[
 {s: "item1", q: 3, $$hashKey: "object:3", population: Object},
 {s: "item2", q: 3, $$hashKey: "object:4", population: Object}
]
```

but when i do

```
console.log($scope.items[0])
```

the output (sometimes*) is:

```
{s: "item1", q: 3, $$hashKey: "object:3"}
```

'* this does not always happen, depends on page load. when refreshing the page, the result is some times with the population and sometimes without.

the first output is always complete with the population intact.
(no matter how manny times i press f5 :) )

i call the console.log at the same time. and in the same order as above.

so i dont understand when i call one of the objects directly they are incomplete?

it looks like a parsing error, **but how can the first output always be complete?**

**Extra info**
the $scope.items is a copy of another array.

i use $http.get to build the object, but also tried to call the console.logs in his success functions.

the $http.get is placed inside a foreach so is called multiple times before the the complete array is complete

and i use the http.get to build the population.

i hope someone can clarify this a bit for me, how this can be possible. or howto continue to look for possibilities to find the error.

Comment: how you get `$scope.items`? and fill population?

Comment: i've noticed recently that when you call `console.log($scope.items)` it's logging by reference but when you do `console.log($scope.items[0])` it's logging by value, try and do `console.log(angular.copy($scope.items))`

Comment: i forget to mention i first copy the object with $scope.items = angular.copy($scope.other);

Comment: @maurycy i did do console.log(angular.copy($scope.items)) and that way it indeed isnt always complete, so i guess this means its a parsing error?

Comment: Can you post all code? including http get

Comment: What do you mean by parsing error? It's rather race issue when you log value before it's processed by some method, you should get familiar with promises and `$http`, you might need something like `$http.get().success(//do fancy stuff).finally(//when fancy stuff is done do even more)`

Comment: I've made working plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/QPB2JW8OAA4TiLgH1g6j?p=preview in this plunker I use `$http` in success method I alter the object and then in `finally` i console.log it and it will ALWAYS be in correct format

Comment: @maurycy oke i will try that, in my case it will be a bit different because the http.get is placed inside a foreach function

Comment: That sound like a very bad idea to call `$http` in `forEach`

Comment: maybe you are right :), i see if i can rewrite my code a bit.

Comment: @maurycy thanks for your help, the finally method did make it work for now. and i see that i need to rewrite my code so the the httpget will not be called in a foreach. please post an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing is a race issue when you log value before it's processed by some method, you should get familiar with promises and $http
Working example for $http and it's promises

http://plnkr.co/edit/QPB2JW8OAA4TiLgH1g6j?p=preview

```
$http.get()
.success(function() {
    $scope.data = [{
      s: "item1",
      q: 3,
      $$hashKey: "object:3"
    }, {
      s: "item2",
      q: 3,
      $$hashKey: "object:4"
    }]
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj){
      obj.population = {}
    })
  })
  .finally(function() {
    console.log($scope.data[0].population)
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not the problem with angular, its feature/problem of google chrome. In google chrome, when you console any object, it shows name:object, when you expand it, it points to real time memory location, and even if that memory location is updated after console.log, it expands with updated output.

```
var d=[];

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    d[i]="val_"+i
}
console.log(d); //d[60] should be val_60 but will get value 'changed value' when you expand
console.log(d[60]); //will print 'val_60'

d[60]='changed value'
```

Here is a sample code which you can run in browser and you will get strange result in console.

In your case, you are printing an array, google chrome's console will point to that array's memory location. and print that array, when you try to expand that array, it will fetch mealtime information from memory and shows you current status of array.

The solution is to use debugger in chrome and inspect that variable before that variable gets change.

Another solution is to convert that array into a string using JSON.stringify,

Comment: oke thanks, but i need to use the population value. and it says Cannot read property 'population' of undefined.

Comment: your population property is not in that object when you are using console.log

Comment: Are you using http call or local storage??

Comment: $http.get inside a foreach, and i also tried to runs the console.logs after the foreach is done

Comment: Then your value gets updated not after your foreach loop, that value gets updated after completion of ajax call which might be in success() or error(). Try to log in success method, you will get your result. you can try promise, but you need to use it as per your logic

Comment: Wow! Thanks for posting this ... I have spent hours looking at "impossible" log output, and can finally understand what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like after first console log some event is removing the population field from the item or may be reinitalizing the items with default values. To debug it better, please log objects with JSON.strinfigy results of the items e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.items)`

Without stringify, any code/event which is altering the object would update the console logs as well.

Comment: there can be events and async operations which can alter the objects even if there is no code between them. And have you checked the results after stringify the objects in console?

Comment: i did now, results are the same